# What is the exact meaning of phrase "deconstructed the many dimensions" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The author says that it is extremely difficult to concentrate during sitting meditation. That's how he describes it:

> "But I couldn't simply sit in a quiet temple without my mind being
>   filled every second with the fireworks of clutter. After a few years I
>   thought I had deconstructed the many dimensions of that moment, but it
>   was upon joining the team at Flow months ago that I realized I still
>   had work to do".

What does the phrase "deconstructed the many dimensions" mean in this text?

I found the term "dimensional deconstruction", but I doubt that it is applicable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_deconstruction

Comment: As far as I am concerned, it doesn't have an exact meaning, or much meaning at all, but seems to be a would-be poetic or mystical way of saying "my mind was still". I may be wrong,though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any specific meaning to do with dimensions, it's just a poetic way of saying "fully understood all the aspects".